# Can someone give me a hint on how to solve this question

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $ f_n:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f_n(x) \geq0 \forall x \in X$ . Assume that for all $x \in X$ the sequence$\{f_n(x) \}_{n=1}^\infty$ decreases monotonically  and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=0 \forall x \in X$

Then prove that $ \lim_{n\to \infty} ( \sup_{x \in X} (f_n(x)))=0$

I thought this question would be easy but I am stuck. From compactness of $X$ we have that the functions $f_n$ are uniformly continuous and I was tried unsuccessfully to bound the the $ \sup_{x \in X} (f_n(x))$using triangle inequality using the fact that  $f_n$ are uniformly continuous but it doesnt work.

Can someone give me a hint. This is a problem in one of the previous functional analysis exams sat my university. Probably this question requires some non-trivial theorem . Any hints would be appreciated. **Please do not give a full solution**

Comment: Google "Dini's Theorem".

Answer (score 2):

Take any $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $$A_n (\varepsilon) =\{x\in X : f_n (x) \geqslant \varepsilon\} .$$ From the asumptions the sets $A_n (\varepsilon)$ are compact $A_n (\varepsilon) \subset A_{n-1} (\varepsilon)$ and $$\bigcap_j A_j (\varepsilon) =\emptyset$$ hence there is $j_0 $ such that $A_{j_0} (\varepsilon)=\emptyset$ which completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: each function is continuous on a compact domain, so the extreme value theorem applies. That is, there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $a_n$ maximises $f_n$ for all $n$. What if $f_n(a_n)$ didn't converge to $0$? What does compactness give us?

Comment: But how can I solve it by using the Baire category theorem?

Comment: I've been thinking about it for the past 45 minutes, and each attempt I make to create some kind of informative countable intersection of open dense sets turns into a use of the topological definition of compactness. Maybe someone else could help you? It might be worth asking the question again, specifically stating you want to use the BCT.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. I really appreciate it