# How can I prove Dini's theorem using the Baire Category theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $ f_n:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f_n(x) \geq0 \forall x \in X$ . Assume that for all $x \in X$ the sequence$\{f_n(x) \}_{n=1}^\infty$ decreases monotonically  and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=0 \forall x \in X$

Then prove that $ \lim_{n\to \infty} ( \sup_{x \in X} (f_n(x)))=0$

I thought this question would be easy but I am stuck. From compactness of $X$ we have that the functions $f_n$ are uniformly continuous and I was tried unsuccessfully to bound the the $ \sup_{x \in X} (f_n(x))$using triangle inequality using the fact that  $f_n$ are uniformly continuous but it doesnt work.

Can someone give me a hint. This is a problem in one of the previous functional analysis exams sat my university.  Any hints would be appreciated. **Please do not give a full solution**

Comment: I don't think that Baire Category Theorem is needed here... I believe compactness should be enough. Remember, a space $X$ is compact $\iff$ any collection of closed subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property has nonempty intersection

Comment: Fix $\epsilon>0$, and set $E_n=\{f(x)\ge\epsilon\}$, which is decreasing and $\bigcap_nE_n=\emptyset$, then there exists $N$ s.t. $E_N=\emptyset$.

Comment: One way (no Baire): Let $\epsilon>0$. Consider the open cover of $X$ given by the  sets  $O_n=\{x\mid g_n(x)<\epsilon\}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362364/can-someone-give-me-a-hint-on-how-to-solve-this-question/1362380 Just so the commenters know, this user has already asked basically this question, and gotten answers, but he specifically wants a proof with BCT.

Answer (score -1):

(Apology for non-math keyboard).Let f(n) be the nth FUNCTION. Suppose by contradiction that , for some r> 0,    we have f(n)(x(n)) > r for infinitely many n, where x(n) belongs to X. Let d be a metric on X. Then the x(n)-sequence has a subsequence x(g(n)) (Where g is strictly  increasing), converging with respect to d ,to a point z. For another hint, for fixed k, consider that f(g(k))(x(g(k+n))) = f(g(k+n))(x(g(x(k+n))).Let n go to infinity.